# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot find my bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth

I recently got Sennheiser HD1 Bluetooth headphones and I cannot seem to connect them to Ubuntu. I set them in pairing mode and they never appear when I am in the Bluetooth menu. They work on other devices.
I have tried googling all over the place, and nothing has seemed to work. I am running a Dell XPS 15. Would anyone here be whiling to help?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following process:

1. Run

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
   ```
2. Change `#AutoEnable=false` to `AutoEnable=true` (at the bottom of the file, by default).
3. Run

   ```
   sudo service /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
   ```

Then your Ubuntu machine maybe would be able to find your BT headphones.